# How to set query timeout in Spring JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have been trying to set query timeout for my spring boot application from last 3-4 days. I gone through more than 5 stackoverflow posts and few blogs. With that learning I tried with below properties but query timeout is not happening. How to set query timeout in spring boot 2.7.14 and java 17, Oracle DB

DB properties

```
spring.datasource.url=***********
spring.datasource.username=*********
spring.datasource.password=*********
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

**try 1**

```
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.query.timeout=1000
spring.jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.lock.timeout=1000
```

**try 2**

```
jakarta.persistence.query.timeout=1000
jakarta.persistence.lock.timeout=1000
```

**try 3**

```
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.lock.timeout=1000
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.query.timeout=1000
```

**try 4**

```
javax.persistence.lock.timeout=1000
javax.persistence.query.timeout=1000
```

**try 5**

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.query.timeout=1
hibernate.query.timeout=1
spring.jdbc.template.query-timeout=1
```

Comment: Please check this thread:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33866

Comment: @HenryXilojHerrera Thanks for replying. I have tried with 2.7.14 boot version also. No luck.